# How do I configure my env.rb file to be able to switch browsers?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ruby, chromedriver, firefoxdriver, watir

Currently, here is part of my configuration with testing using Chrome:

```
    prefs = {
    'download' => {
        'default_directory' => "#{$myRoot}/PDF",
        'prompt_for_download' => false,
    },
    'credentials_enable_service' => false,
    'profile' => {
        'default_content_settings' => {'multiple-automatic-downloads' => 1}, #for chrome version older ~42
        'default_content_setting_values' => {'automatic_downloads' => 1}, #for chrome new 46
        'password_manager_enabled' => false
    }
}

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps['chromeOptions'] = {:prefs => prefs}

client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 600 # seconds – default is 60
client.open_timeout = 600 # seconds – default is 60

# @headless = Headless.new
driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps, :http_client => client

Before do

    @browser = driver
```

I am attempting to allow for use of Firefox as well using a similar set up as I found at http://www.agiletrailblazers.com/blog/advanced-selenium-multiple-browsers-and-environments , specifically by defining a getDriver method which uses a "BROWSER=" parameter in the command line:

```
Before do |scenario|
  $url = getSiteURL
  $driver = getDriver
  $wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 5) # seconds
end

def getDriver
    driverPath = ENV['DRIVERPATH']
    if ENV['BROWSER'] == "firefox"
      if ENV['DRIVERPATH']
        driverPath = ENV['DRIVERPATH'] + '/geckodriver'
        return Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, driver_path: driverPath
      else
        return Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
      end
    elsif ENV['BROWSER'] == "chrome"
      if ENV['DRIVERPATH']
        driverPath = ENV['DRIVERPATH'] + '/chromedriver'
        return Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, driver_path: driverPath
      else
        # This may not work with newer versions of Selenium and firefox
        return Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
      end
    else
      raise Exception.new("Unsupported browser: " + browser)
    end
end
```

I made some changes where I set prefs, caps and client inside the definition, as well as expanding the definition for firefox, however, when I did that, I found that multiple Browser instances were being opened for each Scenario of the feature.

What should I change to avoid this, and how do I configure firefox to behave the same as how I have set up Chrome in the prefs?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of each scenario, you should be quitting the driver instance during teardown:

`$driver.quit`

Comment: But what if I want it to persist between scenarios in a single feature?  For example, if I set one scenario as a login scenario, the next one could be validating elements of a landing page.  If I did a quit between each one, would that not then require me to perform the login again, and thus increase test run-time?

Comment: Yes it increases run time but that is not a reason to not quit.  Tests must be independent of each other, that is a basic requirement.  That means you have two choices:  1. login for each test  2. Find a way to create a login or session that does not use  the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I have found through much more poking around with the items I listed in my original question, which will stop multiple windows from opening, and works with the most recent geckodriver for Firefox.  This actually works now, and now I just have to properly configure the Firefox preferences, and profile as well.  Right now, I cannot seem to get this to quite work and will have the window size fluctuate as opposed to staying maximized, but I would say I am about 90% there

```
def getDriver
    case ENV['BROWSER']
        when "Chrome"
            prefs = {
                'download' => {
                    'default_directory' => "#{$myRoot}/PDF",
                    'prompt_for_download' => false,
                },
                'credentials_enable_service' => false,
                'profile' => {
                    'default_content_settings' => {'multiple-automatic-downloads' => 1}, #for chrome version older ~42
                    'default_content_setting_values' => {'automatic_downloads' => 1}, #for chrome new 46
                    'password_manager_enabled' => false
                }
            }

            caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
            caps['chromeOptions'] = {:prefs => prefs}
            client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
            client.read_timeout = 600 # seconds – default is 60
            client.open_timeout = 600 # seconds – default is 60
            return Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps, :http_client => client
        when "Firefox"
            prefs = {
                'download' => {
                    'default_directory' => "#{$myRoot}/PDF",
                    'prompt_for_download' => false,
                },
                'credentials_enable_service' => false,
                'profile' => {
                    'default_content_settings' => {'multiple-automatic-downloads' => 1}, #for chrome version older ~42
                    'default_content_setting_values' => {'automatic_downloads' => 1}, #for chrome new 46
                    'password_manager_enabled' => false
                }
            }

            caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
            caps['firefoxOptions'] = {:prefs => prefs}
            client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
            client.read_timeout = 600 # seconds – default is 60
            client.open_timeout = 600 # seconds – default is 60
            return Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :desired_capabilities => caps, :http_client => client
    end
end 

# @headless = Headless.new
driver = getDriver
# Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps, :http_client => client

Before do

    # @headless.start
    @browser = driver
    @browser.window.maximize
```